# Angular2 ViewChildren combined with transclusion

Tags: angular, transclusion

When using transclusion in an angular2 component, it appears that my 'ViewChildren' is not able to detect these components. When I make a component where I define the same components directly then it works fine. Does anyone now a way to get this work?

Comment: FYI, we're using the term *content projection* instead of transclusion now.

Comment: Thanks for this nice addition!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can query transcluded content using `@ContentChild()` or `@ContentChildren()`.

`@ViewChild()` and ´@ViewChildren()` only allow to query element in the components template.

See also [angular 2 / typescript : get hold of an element in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this with my error messages component too. Actually you just need to use `ContentChildren` decorator instead of `ViewChildren`. It is made special for ng-content elements. As a result you will get `QueryList` which is iterable object of your components or elements.